# Can we treat discrete variable as continuous variable in regression as one of covariates

Tags: variables, statistics

For example, can we consider the count of emergency room visit as a continuous variable when we do regression?

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is risky to treat a discrete numerical variable as though it is equivalent to a continuous variable. This is especially true if your discrete variable represents some sort of categorical information (e.g. red/blue/green), unless the categories have some natural one-dimensional ordering (e.g. ages grouped into 10-year bands), and the numbers representing the different categories are, in some sense, appropriately spaced when mapped into the continuous space.

In your case, if the discrete variable is a count of patient visits, it may be more reasonable to treat this as though it is a continuous variable, especially if those counts tend to be large. Under those circumstances, it may be more reasonable to assume that the counts resemble random numbers drawn from a Gaussian distribution (following the [Central Limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) theorem), which may fit well with the underlying statistical assumptions of popular regression algorithms. However, if the counts are smaller, or have a high probability of outliers, then it may be more risky to treat them as though they are continuous variables.